# $p$-adic valuation in $\mathbb{Q}$ existence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

For a rational number $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, the claim is that we can write $$ r = p^{e}\cdot\frac{a}{b}, \,\,\, e,a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, b \neq 0 $$
with the properties that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $p$ does not divide $a$ and $b$.

> My question is, how can we verify that this representation is  always possible?

My approach was to write $r :=\frac{c}{d}$ and use the unique prime factorization for $c$ and $d$. Then $e$ is just either $0$ if it does not appear in the prime factorization of $c$ or $d$ or in the other case, just factor out $p$ of the prime factorizations and rewrite $\frac{a}{b}$ without this $p$. But how can we now be sure that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $p$ does not divide $a$ and $b$?

Already, thank you very much for any help!

Comment: This is a *basic* property of fractions. Given *any* fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ with $b\neq 0$, let $d=\gcd(a,b)$; then $a=d\alpha$, $b=d\beta$, $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)=1$, and $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ So you can always write a fraction with numerator and denominator coprime.

Comment: But how do we know that $p$ does not divide $a$ or $b$? I can see why $a$ and $b$ are coprime but that does not imply that p does not divide $a$ and $b$, right?

Comment: You **start** with $\frac{a}{b}$. You then rewrite it as $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$. And because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are relatively prime, no prime can divide both. That means that $p$ divides **either** $\alpha$ **or** $\beta$, and **not both**; you can factor it out. Or you can start from $\frac{a}{b}$, factor out as many powers of $p$ as you can from $a$, say $p^n$. Factor out as many factors of $p$ as you can from $b$, say $p^m$. So $a=p^na'$, $b=p^mb'$, with $p$ not dividing either $a'$ nor $b'$, and write $\frac{a}{b} = p^{n-m}\frac{a'}{b'}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me :)